# How to create and insert json into amazon web services dynamo db in lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

```
dynamo = boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table('Audit')
param = event.get('item')
res = dynamo.put_item(Item = param)
```

i wanted to insert the json which is coming from a event in API Gateway AWS in table in DynamoDB

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks for ur tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your json i like this

```
{
  "item": {
    "item_name": "laddu",
    "short_title": "DAP",
    "description": "This is to create an doctor appointment",
    "cost": "300"
  }
}
```

and python dynamoDb insertion is below

```
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #getting the instance of dynamodb table
    dynamo = boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table(TABLE_NAME)
    #checking weather any record is exist or not
    if (len(dynamo.get_item(Key={'item_name':event.get('item')['item_name']})) > 1):
        result = "Failure"
        msg = "Item Already exist with same name"
    else :
        #inserting the item from the responce
        res = dynamo.put_item(Item = event.get('item'))
        if res["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPStatusCode"] == 200 :
            result = "Success"
            msg = "Item created successfuly"
        else:
            result = "Failure"
            msg = "Failed to create Item"

    #for responce to the user
    data = {}
    data['result'] = result
    data['msg'] = msg
    #construct json object
    json_data = json.dumps(data)

    return json_data
```

This worked for me....